# Find strings using regex and stripping white spaces between them

Tags: python, regex

I have regular expression to find car registration with and without spaces.

```
car_reg_regex = r'([A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z])|([A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{1,4} [A-Z])|([A-Z]{2,3} [0-9]{1,4}[A-Z])|([A-Z]{2,3} [0-9]{3,4} [A-Z])'
```

From input text of "Accident involving our client's SLC 8556 T and GBA 9559 N", I want to remove the spaces only between SLC 8556 T and GBA 9559 N.

```
re.sub(car_reg_regex, text.strip(),input_text)
```

The above python statement is not helping.

Expected output:

```
output_text = "Accident involving our client's SLC8556T and GBA9559N"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the spaces from the match, matching optional spaces on the left and the right without using an alternation `|`

```
import re

pattern = r"[A-Z]{2,3} *[0-9]{1,4} *[A-Z]"
s = "Accident involving our client's SLC 8556 T and GBA 9559 N"
print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group().replace(" " , ""), s))
```

Output

```
Accident involving our client's SLC8556T and GBA9559N
```

A broader match could be matching optional whitespace chars using `\s*` in the pattern, but that could also possibly match a newline.